# Pointer isn't updating value

Tags: c++, r, pointers

I'm running this program to calculate the dot product of two vectors... I'm using *sum as the result, but after initializing it to zero, the value never updates after my loop?

```
extern "C" {
    void attempt2( double * x , double * y, int * len , double * sum , int * ToF){
        *sum = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < *len ; i++ ){
            *sum += x[ i ]*y[ i ];
        } // 
    }
}
```

I then call this in R using .C.

```
x <- c(1.1, 2.1, 3.9)
y <- c(3.0, 1.1, 7.2)
len <- length(x)
Tf <- TRUE
lst <- .C("attempt2", x = x,
          len = len,
          sum = as.numeric(0),
          ToF = as.logical(Tf))
lst
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are not passing y to your function

Comment: one of the arguments is "attempt2" and y is missing

Comment: why do you need ToF, you are not using it in function?

Comment: Of course. That's it.

Comment: posted it as answer in case you need it

Answer (score 0):

You should add y to the arguments:

```
lst <- .C("attempt2", x = x, y = y,
          len = len,
          sum = as.numeric(0),
          ToF = as.logical(Tf))
```

Also not sure you need `ToF` at all.